# magento2 Directly to product if only one

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

Moving from magento 1.9 to 2 -

looking for a way to do some of the things I had done in 1.9, one of those being, that if there's only one product in a category, just go to the product detail page when clicking that category....

just like this, but is there a way to do it in magento 2?
:) thanks in advance!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022430/directly-go-to-product-detail-page-on-click-the-category

EDIT-----

after the response below, I have module in place, but cannot enable said module, how else can it be enabled besides shell access?
I Have tried for hours now, and no success:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit more complex task in comparison with Magento 1. First of all you need to create a small custom extension and modify the block's method behaviour for getting products collection. Magento 2 plugins feature is very handy for this purpose.

create `etc/di.xml` in your extension with the following contents:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="firstproduct-category-mod" type="Vendor\FirstProduct\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

then create the plugin class `Block/Catalog/Product/ListProduct.php` with the code below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\FirstProduct\Block\Catalog\Product;


class ListProduct
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    protected $response;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
    )
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection $resultCollection
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection $resultCollection
     */
    public function afterGetLoadedProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject, $resultCollection)
    {
        if ($resultCollection->count() == 1) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            $product = $resultCollection->getFirstItem();
            $this->response->setRedirect($product->getProductUrl());
        }

        return $resultCollection;
    }
}
```

That's it, we have used DI for Response object injection that allows us to use redirect in case if there's only 1 product in the products collection.

P.S. Do not forget to flush your cache storage after the extension implementation.

Comment: Although not a requirement, convention would dictate plugins should live in [Vendor]/[ModuleName]/Plugin http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: will try this, thank you very much, I am VERY new to Mage2 - so... where you say: create etc/di.xml in your extension, does that mean in a app > design> frontend> ME> MYTHEME  > etc?

Comment: @CVP not at this case. You need to create a separate extension for this purpose. Here you go https://github.com/rogyar/FirstProduct .
You need to put this extension to your Magento installation and enable it.

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza thank you very much! that looks awesome... I uploaded that and cleared the cache, but still not showing, is there some other step to 'enable' it?

Comment: @CVP you need to execute `module:enable` and `setup:upgrade` commands to enable an extension. You can find all details in the official Magento documantation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza I just tried that, and was not successful. Is there any way of doing this without using a command line/shell?

Comment: what I get is 
    ~/public_html/bin]# magento module:status
-bash: magento: command not found

Comment: or when I get to the directory correctly I get "./magento module:status
-bash: ./magento: Permission denied" when logged in as the file system owner I can log in as the user or root, either way, I get "permission denied" - how can I do this without shell access, since shell access does not work?

Comment: @CVP Try to add executive permission to magento binary before: `chmod +x bin/magento`

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza - awesome, that worked! I was able to get that ran now! thank you!.  now that I have done that, I visit the storefront and get this message:  Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /home/cvpedu/public_html/app/code/Atwix/FirstProduct/Block/Catalog/Product/ListProduct.php on line 3

Comment: @CVP looks like there were extra white spaces in the code. I've just fixed this file in the repository. Please, check it out.

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza - you are amazing! and it works awesome, that in my opinion is such am awesome feature to have, not forcing the customer to go through extra clicks to get to the product details...

Comment: This is great, but the xml displayed is missing the closing </config> (this is in your answer, but it's lacking the tab for StackExchange to render it in the code block)

Comment: This code is still useful today, but anyone using it should be aware of 2 things - if the last page of a set of paginated results contains just 1 item, the user will be redirected to that item. Secondly, if a layered navigation filter returns 1 product, activating the filter will take the user away from the category and straight to that product.